# Продлить арест (кого или кому?)

Tags: падежи

Продлить арест (кого или кому?).

Суд продлил арест подозреваемому.Суд продлил арест акционисту Павленскому

Суд по делу Майдана продлил арест трех экс-беркутовцев.

СУД ПРОДЛИЛ АРЕСТ СПЕЦНАЗОВЦЕВ ИЗ РФ ЕРОФЕЕВА И АЛЕКСАНДРОВА НА ДВА МЕСЯЦА

Российские власти планируют продлить арест директора Украинской библиотеки в Москве

Адвокат: прокуратура просит продлить арест генерала МВД Сугробова

Это примеры из СМИ.

Answer (score 2):

СМИ-то явно украинские. А это накладывает некоторый отпечаток на выбор грамматики. )))

Обе формы правильные, но немного в разных ситуациях употребляются. В официозе "арест кому" преобладает. Это связано с тем, что арест понимается не столько как реальный процесс ограничения свободы (тогда "кого" было бы естественным), сколько как решение, административная мера, выполнение которой уже отдельная задача. В таких случаях"кому" идет не от сочетаемости с арестом, а от глагола действия.

Поэтому "**продлить** арест" - кому. "Продлить арест Иванову"
и "**продлить** арест" - кого. "Продлить арест Иванова", но это как бы непрофессионально звучит вне нужного контекста.

А в других случаях, "арест" - кого. "Признать арест Иванова незаконным".

Answer (score 1):

**С точки зрения грамматики оба варианта возможны.**

**(1)** Продлить (что? кому?) арест Иванову, глагол управляет двумя существительными в В.п. и Д.п.

**(2)** Продлить (что?) арест, арест (чей? кого?) Иванова, глагол управляет  В.п.существительного , а существительное  управляет  Р.п. другого существительного.

**Эти варианты имеют различную тематику,** например научную: Правда, радикально продлить жизнь подопытным мышам пока не удалось. Исследователям удалось существенно продлить жизнь мышиных зародышей.

**Однако для неодушевленных  существительных возможен только один вариант**: можно продлить арест имущества, но нельзя продлить арест имуществу.

Comment: Вы запутались. Здесь научной тематикой и не пахнет. Неодушевленность - тем более вторична. Тут важно, что имущество не является субъектом права, а Иванов - субъектом. Коза грамматически тоже одушевлена, но *ей* продлить арест невозможно, поскольку она не стала субъектом.

Comment: А причем тут коза? Я говорю о глаголе "продлить", о том, какими падежами он управляет. И грамматические свойства этого глагола могут относиться к любой теме, в частности к юриспруденции. А также к научной тематике и любым разговорным ситуациям. Например, можно продлить   жизнь  людей и продлить жизнь людям.

Comment: Коза - при одушевленности, которую вы тут приплели ни к селу ни к городу. Глагол "продлить"  сам по себе тем более никому не интересен. Есть выражение "продлить арест", которое вы объяснили через одушевленность - я Вам козу и сделала, чтобы Вы задумались.

Comment: Конфликт семантики и грамматики - вот причина кризисного состояния нашего письма. Люди постоянно путают форму и содержание, например, а некоторые из них уверены, что для судопроизводства создана специальная грамматика и особые правила.

Comment: Может быть, и Вам не трудно будет ЗАДУМАТЬСЯ о семантическом многообразии жизни и об обобщенности грамматических форм, с помощью которых мы это многообразие выражаем. Поэтому, чтобы  "продлить  арест", надо взять словарь и изучить каждое слово в отдельности как часть речи, а потом уже заняться анализом словосочетания, то есть синтаксисом, и уж в самом конце перейти к конкретной семантике. Кстати, "ПРИПЛЕЛИ"  - это невежливое слово, его не рекомендуется использовать  в разговоре  с малознакомыми людьми. После этого пропадает желание к дальнейшему общению